# Can't submit form inside a then()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, submit, croppie

I am trying to submit a form with an image into a php page, i'm using croppie to crop an image and put the result inside an "input" file element, and after that i wish to submit my form.

my js:

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#imagePreview').croppie('result', {
       type: 'canvas',
       size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function (resp) {
       $('#fileInput').val(resp);
       $('#ppForm').submit();
    });
});
```

my html:

```
<form id="ppForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_profile_picture.php" method="post">
   <input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="displayPreview(this)" required>
   <img id="imagePreview" class="croppie-container">
   <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit-button"/>
</form>
```

The problem is, this line `$('#ppForm').submit();` gets skipped for some reason (i've debugged the js using javascript and i see that `$('#fileInput').val(resp);` runs and puts the cropped value into the input, but then the code just ends and no submit happens).
I've also tried to put a break point on that line but it never reaches there.
Why is the submit ignored?

Comment: think posting your form using ajax would be possible , using the `FormData();` object and set your canvas data Image to your FormData object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the value of a `input type="file"` other than to clear it. From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#common-input-element-apis):

> `input . value [ = value ]`
>
> Returns the current value of the form control.
>
> Can be set, to change the value.
>
> **Throws an "[InvalidStateError](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL-1/#invalidstateerror)" [DOMException](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL-1/#idl-DOMException) if it is set to any value other than the empty string when the control is a [File Upload](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-input-file) control.**

*(my emphasis)*

Presumably, you're getting that exception from `val`, which is why the form isn't submitted.

Comment: Yes! that was exactly the problem, weird that i didn't see the error anywhere. I put the value inside a different type of input and everything works fine now. Thank you!